# Apache Drill Schema Support for SQL Server

Tags: apache-drill

I want to know whether Apache Drill supports only **dbo** schema?? or will it support all type of schema?

I am running my system in window 8 and with latest version of Drill(1.5) with embedded mode.

I am trying to search with same storage plugin.

My Storage Plugin(for SQLServer):

```
{
  "type" : "jdbc",
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>;databaseName=<databasename>",
  "username" : "<username>",
  "password" : "<****>",
  "enabled" : true
}
```

This Plugin has **dbo** & **core** schema (*both have same type, no special permission*).Its work for dbo schema where core schema is not working.

DBO Query:

```
select * from SqlServer.dbo.Attribute; //Its working.
```

Core Query:

```
select * from SqlServer.core.Users //Its not working
```

**My question is whether Drill Supports only dbo schemna or all type of schema?**

Comment: enable only **sql server** plugin & fire  `show databases;` from Drill shell. What is the output?

Comment: ITs showing all the databases in that server. I Think dbo is by default schema of sql. show it showing all the table but while query through core (user created) schema, its showing table not found.

Comment: Yes **dbo** is default schema in SQL server. Does `SqlServer.core` is shown with `show databases;` command?

Comment: Ya its showing... but apart from dbo schema i have other schema also.. those schemas are not showing (i.e core, D21) are not showing.. only dbo is showing

Comment: I am confused `SqlServer.core` is shown or not? I know `SqlServer.dbo` is shown.

Comment: no SqlServer.core is not showing

Comment: @dev: core and other user created schema are not showing..

Comment: @dev: Extremely sorry for confusing you . SqlServer.Core is not showing.

Comment: no problem Sanjiv. I will try this at my end.

Comment: How did you create core & other schemas?

Comment: In Sql Server database we have created some tables in dbo schema and we have created some more schemas (i.e core, p21,etc) and created some tables in those schemas. Now only those table which are created in dbo are accessable through drill. But tables from other schemas are not showing. I Have create schema using this query :- Create schema core.

Comment: @dev:  
In Sql Server database we have created some tables in dbo schema and we have created some more schemas (i.e core, p21,etc) and created some tables in those schemas. Now only those table which are created in dbo are accessable through drill. But tables from other schemas are not showing. I Have create schema using this query :- Create schema core.

Comment: not much familiar with SQL server, but I created a schema using `create schema testschema` & added table in this schema. I am able to query over this table via JDBC. This schema is not shown in drill. I have not looked drill's source code yet to get the exact issue. This could be a bug. You can ask on **drill user group**. Mention every thing how did you create schema and table in that schema, drill version, OS and all.

Comment: @dev: I have send mail to user@drill.apache.org  this id now. But previously i have send mail to them about some other issues, but they didn't reply.

Comment: you raised a bug on JIRA for that?

Comment: @dev: Ya dev, I have raise a bug in jira..

Comment: you can answer your question with details of bug and all

Comment: @dev: I think I found out solution for that.. Check it out my answer dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from <StoragePluginName>.<databaseName>.<schemaName>.<tableName>;
```

Ex:

```
seleect * from SqlServer.Test.core.Category;
```

> This query  will work  for all type of  user created schemas. But for dbo(default) schema
>   Databases name is not required. If you write database name while query through dbo
>   schema, it will through error.
>
> **--> But This not the good solution. Because every time we have check for
>   schema (default or user created schema). If it has dbo (default
>   schema) then database name is not required in query. And If it has
>   core (user created schema) schema then we have to give database name
>   after Storage Plugin.**